# Bendable UHF Whip Antenna for RFID Scanner

Tags: rfid

I'm building an RFID scanning apparatus, which is going to be attached to a potato harvester, and I'm trying to find a suitable antenna. Because of where said antenna is going to be placed on the harvester, it will have to be extremely rugged. The word *rugged* in this context means:

- It can withstand being bashed against various surfaces: the ground, wooden boxes, hedgerows, etc. (I thought perhaps a "whip" kind of antenna, which could bend rather than break under pressure, might be suitable, but I don't know where to find one.)
- It is resistant to damage from wind and rain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rugged, think repairable/replaceable. You could use any mount and adapt it to take a length of 2 mm dia. (12 gauge) copper wire. If bent, it can be straightened by hand, and if broken, replaced for <

An advantage of the less robust approach is that soft copper wire is less likely to cause damage to the harvester if ingested, or to personnel. Think "just small potatoes".